# File format for importing from Autodesk and Tinker CAD?

Tags: import, file-format

How can I import 3D models created in Autodesk and Tinker cad into Blender 2.69?  What file format should they be saved in?

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE! Please let us know what you've tried and what hasn't worked. If you haven't tried it yourself, we can't do much to help. There are lots of other places with great tutorials for using Blender. For this question, it's also important to know which Autodesk product you're using.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your response.  I saved it as every possible file including stl, psd, and obj, and then tried to open in blender 2.69 but kept getting the error message that it can't open in blender. Not sure what Im doing wrong.  I have no problem opening the files in photoshop cc.  I watched the all the online free tutorials to learn basic basic blender 3d modeling and for help with importing and read the manual. Unfortunately most tutorials are not for 2.69 although there are a few.  What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Blender SE!

**Which Autodesk product are you using?**

[This documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Import) talks about what file types Blender can import. Depending on what Autodesk product you're using, Blender might be able to just open the file that it uses. OBJ is usually the most widely supported, but materials can be difficult and it doesn't support any proprietary features: OBJ will only export the mesh and sometimes materials (no shapes, no rigs, no animations, etc).

I can't tell for sure, but I'd be willing to wager than Tinker supports exporting OBJ files.

If all you want is the model, OBJ is your best bet. In which case:

- Export your original file as an OBJ
- Open Blender and File -> Import... your OBJ into a new scene, or a scene you've already started.

Comment: When I go to open the design saved as an obj, blender is not on the list of applications to open the file with.  I'm using the fee basic blender program, not blender professional, and maybe it's restricted???

Comment: There's no such thing as Blender Pro. Windows (or Mac) is the one telling you what you should open that file with, and it may not actually know about Blender. Furthermore, you can't open the file directly, you have to import it. You'll have to open Blender and choose File -> Import -> Wavefront OBJ...

Comment: ...and if anyone ever tries to get you to pay for Blender, you should punch them in the head ;-) Blender is totally open-source, which means they never sell any part of it (though it's not illegal to sell Blender, or a reformulation of Blender, so long as you also say that it can be downloaded for free at Blender.org).

Comment: Right, sorry, not blender pro, was confusing it with photoshop.  Following you advice it opened with wavefront obj, many, many, thanks.